# C# VS 2010 Winforms: TabOrder goes backwards

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabindex

I made a winform for logging in on my C# project and I assigned the tab index for each object. The order has to be the following:

- Text Box User
- Text Box Password
- Button OK
- Button Cancel.

When I press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key at runtime the order goes backwards. I did it also with the tab order but it happens the same. How can I change it?

Comment: Can you post an [image with tab indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd16a8cw(v=vs.90).aspx) of your controls?

Comment: What are the tab indeces you have set? Have you set them backwards by accident?

Comment: Setting the order you want using VIEW -> TabOrder menu command doesn't work?

Comment: I already found the problem, see the answer below.

Comment: @MarialvyMartínez there is no mentioning of other languages in your question

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I forgot about the languages. I made all forms in 4 different languages but I forgot completely about that fact. I am making an edit of the question and I will include them there.

Comment: @MarialvyMartínez question already have answers, so it's not good to edit it

Comment: I did the explanation in my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:

I made all forms in my app in four languages: English, Dutch, French and German. I set the order in just the Dutch language. So there has to be kept in mind that for every language the user has to configure the tab order or the tab index. I did the changes in the other three languages and it works perfectly.

Comment: Wouldn't your needs have been better met with satellite resource assemblies?  As it stands now, your code probably has logic to determine which dialog to show and repeated code within each dialog.

Comment: @BradBruce I use the resources assemblies, but that doesn't work with the tab functions, there I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 3):

From [TabIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) remarks:

> A tab index can consist of any valid integer greater than or equal to
>   zero, lower numbers being earlier in the tab order.

From your description of problem, it looks like you have tab indexes in descending order. I suggest you to use Tab Order view to set tab indexes by clicking on your controls in desired order as described in article [How to: Set the Tab Order on Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd16a8cw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Final result should look like:

[image]